# How to use perf_event_open under sampling mode to read the value of BRANCH STACK?

Tags: branch, sample, perf

I use `perf_event_open()` under sampling mode to sample the value of branch stack, but I don't know why!!

```
attr.sample_type=PERF_SAMPLE_IP|PERF_SAMPLE_BRANCH_STACK
```

if I don't set `PERF_SAMPLE_BRANCH_STACK` to `attr.sample_type`,  everything is ok!!  I don't know why!!!!!!!!!!

```
     static int perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr *attr,
         pid_t pid,int cpu,int group_fd,unsigned long flags)
     {
         return syscall(__NR_perf_event_open,attr,pid,cpu,group_fd,flags);
     }

     int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {

        pid_t pid = 0;
       // create a perf fd
        struct perf_event_attr attr;
        memset(&attr,0,sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
        attr.size=sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
    // disable at init time
        attr.disabled=1;
    // set what is the event
        attr.type=PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
        attr.config=PERF_COUNT_HW_BRANCH_INSTRUCTIONS;
    // how many clocks to trigger sampling
        attr.sample_period=1000000;
    // what to sample is IP
        attr.sample_type=PERF_SAMPLE_IP|PERF_SAMPLE_BRANCH_STACK;
    // notify every 1 overflow

        attr.wakeup_events=1;
        attr.branch_sample_type = PERF_SAMPLE_BRANCH_ANY_RETURN;
    // open perf fd
        int perf_fd=perf_event_open(&attr,pid,-1,-1,0);
        if(perf_fd<0)
        {
            perror("perf_event_open() failed!");
            return errno;
        }
```

> failed! error : Operation not supported!

Comment: what hardware are you running this on?  IIRC Broadwell introduced support for `intel_pt`, but https://lwn.net/Articles/680985/ says Last Branch Record (LBR) has been around since Netburst (Pentium 4) on Intel.  IDK about AMD.

Comment: My experimental environment is that my cpu is Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7300HQ，system: windows 10, my code run on vmware, my guest system is linux mint 19.01 (linux kernel 4.15).

Comment: Many VMs don't pass through HW perf counters and similar stuff to guest VMs at all.  See if `perf stat /bin/ls` can even get counts for `cycles` and `branches` (on by default).

Comment: First，thanks for your answer!  I found that vmware can't virtualize the LBR (branch_stack).SO,  I decided to give up vmware and  install Ubuntu on my  computer! See what happened next!

Answer (score 2):

I can think of three reasons why would that error occur in your case:

- You're running the code on an IBM POWER processor. On these processors `PERF_SAMPLE_BRANCH_STACK` is supported and some of the branch filters are supported in the hardware, but `PERF_SAMPLE_BRANCH_ANY_RETURN` is not supported on any of the current POWER processors. You said that the code works fine by removing `PERF_SAMPLE_BRANCH_STACK`, but that doesn't tell us whether the problem is from `PERF_SAMPLE_BRANCH_STACK` or `PERF_SAMPLE_BRANCH_ANY_RETURN`.
- You're running the code on a hypervisor (e.g., KVM). Most hypervisors (if not all) don't virtualize branch sampling. Yet the host processor may actually support branch sampling and maybe even the `ANY_RETURN` filter.
- The processor doesn't support the branch sampling feature. These include Intel processors that are older than the Pentium 4.

Not all Intel processors support the `ANY_RETURN` filter in hardware. This filter is supported starting with Core2. However, on Intel processors, for branch filters that are not supported in the hardware, Linux provides software filtering, so `PERF_SAMPLE_BRANCH_ANY_RETURN` should still work on these processors.

There could be other reasons that I have missed.

Answer (score 0):

> error : Operation not supported

The [perf_event_open() manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) says about this error:

```
       EOPNOTSUPP
              Returned if an event requiring a specific hardware feature is
              requested but there is no hardware support.  This includes
              requesting low-skid events if not supported, branch tracing if
              it is not available, sampling if no PMU interrupt is
              available, and branch stacks for software events.
```

And about `PERF_SAMPLE_BRANCH_STACK` it says:

```
          PERF_SAMPLE_BRANCH_STACK (since Linux 3.4)
                 This provides a record of recent branches, as provided
                 by CPU branch sampling hardware (such as Intel Last
                 Branch Record).  Not all hardware supports this fea‐
                 ture.
```

So it looks like your hardware doesn't support this.

Comment: First，thanks for your answer!   My experimental environment is that my cpu is Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7300HQ，system: windows 10, my code run on vmware, my guest system is linux mint 19.01 (linux kernel 4.15)。